# How to set celery task status when uncaught exception raised

Tags: python, task, celery

I have celery task

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    try:
        return call_another_function(x, y)
    except ValueError as ex:
        handle_value_error(ex)
```

I am handling `ValueError`, but what if `call_another_function` raise other exception like `IOError` or `IndexError`?

Celery has any mechanism, where we can set like `app.call_for_any_exception` and that method call if we not handle the exception in our code?

I just want to make sure, if there are any exception, my task should be in `fail` state.

I am using `celery v4.0.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another except clause without any exceptions to catch:

```
try:
    return call_another_function(x, y)
except ValueError as ex:
    handle_value_error(ex)
except:
    update_state(state=FAILED)
    raise
```

If you want a solution for many task, you can use this way proposed in [the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-inheritance):

```
class MyTask(celery.Task):

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        self.update_state(state=FAILED)

@task(base=MyTask)
def add(x, y):
    try:
        return call_another_function(x, y)
    except ValueError as ex:
        handle_value_error(ex)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I dont know, how many exception it can raise. There are multiple task in `app`, if I have to add `except:` block, then I have to modify each task. I am looking for general entry point where we can put barrier.